# Darken Map View when Annotation Clicked/Viewed

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, android-mapview, mkannotation

Is it possible to make the Mapview darken/decrease the alpha over a black background (similar to viewing images in a JS/CSS lightbox) when a annotation is clicked (which in turn shows a custom View over the lower portion of the map (in essence a small details box).

If anyone has done it, if a snippet / rough idea could be given that would be great.

If it's possible, would apple reject such design? I dont see why they would however its potentially decreasing the view of the google maps view temporarily...

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the delegate methods of MKMapViewDelegate to detect when the annotations are selected and deselected. When selected, like you said, decrease the alpha of the MKMapView over a black background to darken. Alternatively, increase the alpha of a black overlay thats on top of the MKMapView. When annotation is deselected you go back to normal. I don't think something like this would be rejected but no one can ever be 100% positive of Apple's approval decisions.